# PyQt4 and QtWebKit - how to auto scroll the view?

Tags: python, pyqt, qwebview

I got a `QtWebKit.QWebView` widget in a PyQt application window that I use to display text and stuff for a chat-like application.

```
    self.mainWindow = QtWebKit.QWebView()
    self.mainWindow.setHtml(self._html)
```

As the conversation gets longer the vertical scrollbar appears.

What I'd like to get, is to scroll the displayed view to the bottom when it's needed. How can I do it? Or, maybe, I shouldn't use `QWebView` widget for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kender - The QWebView is made up of a QWebPage and a QWebFrame.  The scroll bar properties are stored in the QWebFrame, which has a setScrollBarValue() method, as well as a scrollBarMaximum() method to return the max position.

See these links for details:
  [QWebView](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebview.html), 
  [QWebFrame](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwebframe.html)

Answer (score 3):

For (Py)Qt 4.5, use frame's scroll position, e.g. self._html.page().mainFrame().setScrollPosition. See [QWebFrame::setScrollPosition()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwebframe.html#scrollPosition-prop) function..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe JavaScript is the easiest way, but you may also use `evaluateJavaScript` function of `QWebView`:

```
self.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("window.scrollTo(0, "+str(self.init_ypos)+");")
```

where `self` is a class `Browser(QWebView)` (`self.mainWindow` for you).